# Как получить сырой буфер кодированных аудио-данных в libvorbis?

Tags: c++, аудио

Необходимо сжимать кодеком vorbis PCM сэмплы с аудио-входа. В найденном [примере](https://github.com/xiph/vorbis/blob/master/examples/encoder_example.c) показано кодирование WAV в ogg, а в [документации](https://xiph.org/vorbis/doc/libvorbis/reference.html) структура `vorbis_block`, которая предположительно и хранит буфер с кодированными данными, не имеет `public`-членов. Мне ogg ни к чему. Требуется компоновать видео VP8 и аудио vorbis в контейнере WebM, и для этого нужны исходные кодированные данные, не "завёрнутые" в какой-либо медиа-контейнер. С видео давно разобрался, с WebM тоже... с аудио не понятно - **как получить сырой буфер со сжатыми аудио-пакетами после операции кодирования**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Указатель на сырой буфер с данными и его размер можно найти в структуре [`ogg_packet`](https://xiph.org/ogg/doc/libogg/ogg_packet.html), которая заполняется после успешного вызова `vorbis_bitrate_flushpacket`. Использование этой структуры не подразумевает обязательную привязку к ogg.